# Reversed biased condition np junction

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Well there are a few posts about the reverse biased condition but I have a problem understanding one thing.

[Why doesn't current flow in reverse biased diode?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94915/why-doesnt-current-flow-in-reverse-biased-diode)

It the picture there are positive charged atoms on the edge of the p-type region and free electrons with a negative charge on the edge of the n-type region

Don't those carriers attract/repel electrons so electricity can flow through the circuit?

Comment: Hint: how much current flows through a reverse-biased PN junction?

Comment: none but I would really like to know why those carriers dont attract/repel electrons

Comment: @MaxDestiny In the link you posted, John Rennie's answer is valid. You read it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the depiction you linked is incorrect.

As the charge carriers migrate across the junction, they reach an equilibrium so that positive charges build-up **on the n-side** of the junction, while negative build-up on the P-side. You can check from other sources.

This creation of charge (in that way) is precisely what is gonna stop current from flowing. It creates a voltage barrier that will repel any electron that wants to go from the n-side to the p-side (If you had your charges the other way around, then the voltage would actually pull the electrons to the p-side). Applying reverse bias basically pulls charge carriers away from the junction and increases the width of this depletion region. Therefore, the reverse bias increases this potential barrier that opposes the natural flow of charge carriers.

Comment: so where can I find a better depiction?

Comment: I know this but holes dont have free electrons so those electrons need to migrate from somewhere (silicon)

Comment: Simply, wikipedia, which will give you a drawing of the situation with the charges on the correct sides (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P–n_junction). Sorry, I do not understand what you mean by "holes dont have free electrons", or which électrons you refer to when you say "those elctrons" :S

Comment: never mind I understood it by myself